# how to applied time Linked Pickers in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

i am trying to adjust the start time and end time fields  in this  way that when the user select start time than end time field must be greater than start time.
please tell me how i resolve my problem

view code

```
<fieldset>
                        <label for="input-two" class="float"><strong>Start Time:</strong></label><br />
                        <input class="inp-text" name="starttime"  id="input-two" type="time" size="30" />
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset>
                        <label for="input-two" class="float"><strong>End Time:</strong></label><br />
                        <input class="inp-text" name="endtime"  id="input-two" type="time" size="30" />
                    </fieldset>
```

controller code

```
public function store()
{

    $dev = new updatetask();
    $dev->start_time =Input::get('starttime');
    $dev->end_time = Input::get('endtime');
    $dev->save();
    return redirect('updatetask');
}
```

please guide me what check i applied in controller code

Answer (score 0):

You can use laravel amazing "[validation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation)" component like this:

```
public function store(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
       'starttime' => 'date',
       'endtime'   => 'date|after:starttime',
    ]);
    // The above will now return redirect back with the input and the error messages if any error exist.
    // Else, if everythings ok:
    $dev = new updatetask();
    $dev->start_time = $request->input('starttime');
    $dev->end_time = $request->input('endtime');
    $dev->save();
    return redirect('updatetask');
}
```